# How to integrate application code into MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I made a program that does some calcualtions for which I want to create a GUI using WPF and MVVM.
I'm not sure how to connect the internal variables of my applications to the Model Properties that the View will react to.
What I mean is, if my application is working with an internal variable `n`, whenever that changes value, in order for the change to be reflected in the View I have to manually update the Model's propriety as well.

What's the better way to integrate my application into MVVM?

Here is my current code (simplified):

```
class ApplicationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members
    private int number;
    #endregion

    public ApplicationModel()
    {
        new Thread(() => applicationWork(this)).Start();
    }

    private void applicationWork(ApplicationModel appModel)
    {            
        // internal variables
        int n = 0

        // simulating my app running, changing variables
        while (true)
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            n++;
            appModel.number++;
            // how do I tie the two together?            
        }        
    }

    #region Properties
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
        set
        {
            number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // ...
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Does your model currently provide functionality to notify someone whenever its state changes, for example by raising an event? If not, can you modify the implementation of the model do do this? Then it's just a matter of implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever you want the view to refresh. If the model doesn't provide any change notifications, you will have to poll it regularly to detect any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, `appModel.number++;` is modifying the private backing variable, which won't update the setter for `Number`, and thus the PropertyChanged event won't be called. I consider it good practice to always modify the public member.

Looks like you can do some consolidation of variables (is `n` always the same as `Number`? Why not just modify `Number`?) to clean things up.

Comment: You are understanding correctly. I have developed my app separately only relying on CMD for feedback, so now, I want to create a gui for it. Changing all the internal variables for the Model properties like you suggest would work, I'm just woundering if that's how things are usually made in MVVM, e.g. using the Model Properties as your application variables.

Comment: In MVVM you typically have a ViewModel, The model stores data in whatever way is convenient for the model, the View needs a specific formatting for binding, the ViewModel is that translator between the two.  The model can be whatever form you like, if you want to use the application as the model, that's not wrong, but typically your application would not act as the ViewModel as you've done here.  The model should not concern itself with what the view is doing, that loosely coupled relationship is what makes MVVM so powerful.